# Different values for my IP address?

Tags: networking, tcp, ipconfig

Was just wondering why I seem to get different values for my IP address from different sources. If I go to one of the many different 'what's my ip' sites on the net I get a completely different value from when I use ipconfig (on win7)

And no, it's not the subnet mask I'm looking at, these are the actual ipv4 addresses, why would they be resolving to different addresses? Are these 'what's my IP' sites only able to hit an exchange and not determine the IPs of my actual box itself?

Comment: ipconfig is showing the local adress while your box is probably assigning a new public address to each connection between your computer and the server

Comment: Can you post the domain name so we can check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PC is on a network and not directly connected to your ISP via a modem, there will be at least one router between your machine and the internet. That router will almost certainly be doing [NAT (Network Address Translation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) and possibly [DHCP (Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) too.

The router will have been assigned an address by the ISP when it established the connection. This address might be static (unchanging) or, more commonly, dynamic (changes periodically as the ISP sees fit). So your 'public' address - the one the router has been assigned and which is visible to the internet - may change from time to time.

Your PC will be connected to the router, and will either have a fixed IP address assigned to it (typically in the 192.168.x.x range) through your OS networking config, or will be given one by the router each time it connects (when you switch on or reboot) via DHCP. In this case, the address will be in whatever range the DHCP service has been told to use (again, the default is likely to be in the 192.168.x.x range).

So your PC has its' own internal address, and your router has its' public address. When you exchange internet traffic, the machine at the other end of the connection will see your public address, not your internal address - the router takes care of forwarding data to the right internal address automatically.

Depending on what IP-checker service you're using, it might display your public address (from the router, which may change if the ISP assigns dynamic addresses) or your internal address (typically when a script runs inside the browser and asks the machine directly).

Comment: Cool, excellent answer. It's one of the things I've always noticed but never bothered finding out before.

Answer (score -1):

The answer won't clarify anything, but I'll tell you anyway.

They're both right.

No, your machine doesn't really have two IP addresses, but the IP it shows as depends on who's looking, and from where.

•

What you're seeing is the result of what's called a NAT router. NAT stands for "Network Address Translation". The router manages the IP addresses on a LAN, or Local Area Network, and then translates to the appropriate IP address it was assigned on the external network, usually the internet.

[details](http://ask-leo.com/why_doesnt_my_machines_ip_address_match_what_im_told_on_the_internet.html)